# kernel / initd boot settings

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, kernel

I have 2 seperate harddrives in my pc, one with windows 7 (working) and one with ubuntu. I am unable to boot into ubuntu for some reason :/ I installed easyBCD to correct the windows bootmenu and used neogrub to manually set my ubuntu boot option. Here's the issue, though. I am able to get into grub2 and see the ubuntu 14.04 option, but when I select it, it says "file not found" for the kernel. I think my neogrub options are wrong in some way :/

Here's my neogrub options:

```
title Ubuntu
find --set-root /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.17-10-generic
kernel /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.17-10-generic ro root=/dev/sda2
initrd /boot/initrd.img-2.6.17-10-generic
```

the root drive selection is correct. I have a total of 3 harddisks (1 OS SSD and one storage for my windows install and sda2 for ubuntu). Does ubuntu 14.04 use another kernel file than what I've put in?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Why would you ask about neogrub and settings on Ubuntu forum ?

Is neogrub part of Ubuntu ?

Moreover neogrub is a pirated version of grub4dos as it does not comply to GPL !

**Please supply link to source code of neogrub and your question will be answered.**